# Qt compiler cannot find the header file

Tags: c++, qt, header-files

I know it's a quite common issue but I haven't found a comprehensive answer on the following question.
I have Qt 5.4.1 MSVC2013 build running on Windows 8.1.
Here is a look on my project files:

[image]

And here is what my .pro file looks like:

```
QT       += core gui

greaterThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 4): QT += widgets

TARGET = Vfp
TEMPLATE = app

QMAKE_CXXFLAGS = - std=c++11

SOURCES += main.cpp\
        Views/mainview.cpp

HEADERS  += Views/mainview.h

FORMS    += Views/mainview.ui
```

The problem is, unless I add `INCLUDEPATH += Views/` to the .pro file, I cannot include `mainview.h` in `main.cpp` file.

Why? Shouldn't `HEADERS  += Views/mainview.h` be enough?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're including the header file this way:

```
#include "mainview.h"
```

Then yes, you need to add that include path since the compiler (not the IDE) doesn't know where mainview.h is.
Otherwise, you need to specify the relative path to the file, like:

```
#include "Views/mainview.h"
```

Comment: So then, what's the point of writing `HEADERS  += Views/mainview.h` ?

Comment: Looks like it's for adding it to the files list in that project view

Comment: Ok, after further reading, not only for project view. qmake uses this for its own parsing, so basically for project compilation management, sort of like a makefile. But you still need to add relative paths to include directives, as the compiler itself needs that.

Answer (score 0):

[Documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qmake-variable-reference.html#headers) doesn't say that HEADERS is for specifying include paths to the compiler. HEADERS is used for generating dependency information and checking whether moc is necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you add below command to `.pro` file you will able to compile it.

```
INCLUDEPATH += ...path/Views/
```